# Windows Azure CDN using https - connection reset

Tags: https, azure, cdn

I keep having a problem where I'll randomly get connection resets when trying to access static content from the Azure CDN using https.

I have enabled HTTPS on the cdn endpoint and most of the time it works fine, but sometimes it's like it just hangs and no https links to the cdn works. If I change to http it keeps working fine and after about 10 minutes or so the https "comes back up".

Anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this problem too when you are connecting from your local machine?

Any way, what you could to do is using Fiddler on your Azure Instance and on your local machine to see if you get more information from it.

That would be my first step is attacking the problem.